# Rubber not starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I used `complete_passenger_mysql` recipe and successfully deployed the app.

Last command I saw was, `'* 2013-11-10 03:36:59 executing`cleanup''`,  and then it automatically ended the session, without any error. 
So, I guess, deployment was successful.

Now, when I try to browse my app, it just lists files/directories of my app's `public` directory ( 404.html, 422.html, 500.html , assets folder etc.)

So, I think apache is working fine. But rails server is not live. Do I need to do anything special for that ? I just did `cap deploy` to deploy the app.

Answer (score 0):

please check the log file on server

```
deployed_path/current/log/production.log
```

or you can try this in console of the server

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

The db config will make issue if it's wrong.

```
config/database.yml
```

Comment: `production.log` is empty. `cap rubber:tail_logs` does not show anything. What should I do with the console ?

Comment: please check if you added passenger module in apache config.

Comment: Yes, it's there. Also, I see [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubber-ec2/PYSn3koYXbI) is similar to my problem

Comment: Sorry, nothing related with passenger in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. But in passenger conf I have apache entry.

Comment: the apache config should include passenger module and passenger config. e.g. LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby

Comment: Actually, I noticed that apache is loading `passenger.conf` file thus it has this entry. But I checked the apache logs and found this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426666/unable-to-start-the-phusion-passenger-watchdog

Comment: As I mentioned already, you must indicate valid passenger config. PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10

Comment: still not solve problem? if you give me the access of the AWS, i can fix for you.

Comment: Yeah, confs are okay. I used rubber to install passenger. But, it had an old version of passenger which was not compatible with ruby 2.0. I then changed the passenger version and run the bootstrap command again. I guess, I installed two passengers and they were conflicting. I stopped working on the issue. destroyed the instance and now installing again.