# Troubleshooting Rails nginx+passenger 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to figure out why nginx is returning 500 Internal Server Error. Initially I had this app running in standalone mode with Passenger, but I intend on hosting a few other applications now, and I can't get this app past this point using nginx to serve the requests. I *can* get the app running with WEBrick, but that's not at all going to work for the goals at hand right now.

I'm not using capistrano or any type of automated builders, and this is running on a linode VPS. It ran fine about ten months ago before linode rebooted the hardware, and after that reboot it's been dead. That was about 10 months ago, so before embarking on this journey, I updated all packages on the system, in case that has any influence on the problem.

This is what I get when trying to start the app:

```
$ bundle exec passenger start
Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.

Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

Here is my environment:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.8-x86_64-linode117 (maker@build.linode.com) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 18 18:48:25 UTC 2018

$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.1

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.2

$ gem -v
2.7.7
```

nginx.conf:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    # include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf 
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby;


# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/site 
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /var/www/site/code/public;
    rails_env production;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;                # prevents page from being embedded in other pages
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;      # prevents MIME type sniffing
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";    # prevents XSS rendering
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;                   # prevents robots from crawling the requested page
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";                   # don't store a cached version of the site resources
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";            # don't store a cached version of the site resources
        add_header X-uri "$uri";                        # requested URI
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;       # required for Google fonts (CORS strikes again)
    }
}
```

pg_hba.conf

```
# cat /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf 
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.




# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

`site-enabled/` has symlinks to configuration files in `sites-available/`.

I receive the following, and yet the whole reason I attempted to run this command was to resolve the error it's complaining about.

```
$ passenger-config compile-agent --force
Checking for required software...

 * Checking for C compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/cc
 * Checking for C++ compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/c++
Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.

Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

Checking `/var/log/ngingx/error.log` shows me:

```
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] Started GET "/" for [REDACTED] at 2018-10-18 19:18:43 -0700
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   Rendered shared/_tweets.html.erb (1.2ms)
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (10.9ms)
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   Rendered shared/_application_nav.html.erb (20.4ms)
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 541ms
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] ActionView::Template::Error (FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "[REDACTED]"
App 26325 output: ):
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     3:     <h3 class="masthead-brand">Site Name</h3>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     4:     <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     5:       <%= nav_generator 'nav-link', 'span' %>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     6:       <%= login_helper 'nav-link' %>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     7:     </nav>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     8:   </div>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]     9: </div>
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158]   
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] app/models/concerns/current_user_concern.rb:9:in `guest_user'
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] app/models/concerns/current_user_concern.rb:5:in `current_user'
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `login_helper'
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] app/views/shared/_application_nav.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_shared__application_nav_html_erb___1001043723099543592_69980262645600'
App 26325 output: [d3f637be-1308-4fdc-ad97-d0476633b158] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:48:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4053957196745232794_40927140'
```

Already referenced documentation:

[Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426666/unable-to-start-the-phusion-passenger-watchdog)

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/ruby.html#bundle-exec-rails-server

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/ruby/#first-things-to-try

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4i0m8j/migrate_from_webrick_to_phusion_passenger/

https://serverfault.com/questions/362697/nginx-passenger-returning-500s-for-every-request

https://medium.com/@maciejmensfeld/ruby-2-5-0-upgrade-remarks-100d7c0dd73d

https://www.linode.com/docs/development/ror/ruby-on-rails-nginx-debian/

I know I'm forgetting some additional information that may help, so if you have an idea and need more details, let me know exactly what you need and I'll get update the post. Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

`Peer authentication failed for user "[REDACTED]"`

That looks like a database authentication issue.  Do you have the proper environmental variables setup to allow you to connect from rails to your database AND pg_hba.conf setup to allow proper auth?

Side note: if that is the case, you may consider tightening that up to not be peer based auth and use something strong.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html

Comment: I chased that down, but what doesn't make sense is why can I run this app with WEBrick and not Passenger? If I run rails s -e production, I can access site.com:3000 fine. So I'm wondering if that's a secondary issue?

Comment: I've added pg_hba.conf to the question.