# Web application could not be started after deployment in digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, digital-ocean

-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Your bundle is locked to activesupport (4.2.8), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of activesupport (4.2.8) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of activesupport (4.2.8) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound). I have updated ruby from 2.2.4 to 2.4.0 in server

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj34z.png)

Comment: Did you tried what the image says? It seems that you have rvm installed on your server and need to update the wrapper for the new ruby version with a new gemset

Comment: Yeah, I have done that, later I found out that I have to update passenger_root path in my nginx conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set the correct path for passenger_root in my nginx.conf file. Though after that nginx was not starting, from error.log file (nginx), I found out that I have to do some compiling. I followed the instructions there, also looked into this [Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426666/unable-to-start-the-phusion-passenger-watchdog)

command line

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.30/bin/passenger-config compile-agent